# Count values in a column that are not in a list - excel

Tags: excel

I'm looking for a way to count values in a column that are NOT in a list.

Example would be employees filling out a form but spelled their name wrong. I'd like to count the instances where the names aren't in my list of employees. There's 65 employees in the list.

Comment: `COUNTA( T1[Names] ) - SUMPRODUCT( COUNTIFS( T2[List], T1[Names] ))`

Answer (score 2):

To count wrong spelled name use `COUNTIFS()` function.

```
=SUM(--((COUNTIFS(F2:F6,B2:B6)=0)))
```

If you want find list of wrong spelled names then could try-

```
=FILTER(B2:B6,COUNTIFS(F2:F6,B2:B6)=0)
```

[image]

Comment: If I had a date column, how would I add a date filter?

Comment: Something like `=FILTER(B2:B6,(COUNTIFS(F2:F6,B2:B6)=0)*(DateCol>=StartDate)*(DateCol<=EndDate))`. If the answer help then please tick mark it to treat it as solved.